# Is there bulletproof way to copy another workbook using vba?

Tags: excel, vba

This is bothering me for a years now, I would like to open another workbook using VBA and copy worksheet to the current workbook and close it. Another workbook can be also macro enabled workbook. My method is following:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Dim workBookName1 As String
Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable
Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityLow
Workbooks.Open fileName:="C:\test.xlsm", ReadOnly:=True
workBookName1 = ActiveWorkbook.Name

'some work with copying, filtering, etc.

With Workbooks(workBookName1)
    .Close
End With
```

BUT the issue is that is not bulletproof -> sometimes this procedure closes all opened workbooks.

is there any other way to deal with this, maybe another method to try it?

Comment: A little confusing: Do you mean you want to open another workbook and copy a workSHEET from it? Copying a workbook into another workbook doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: Open workbook A then save as workbook B. Then open B as the current workbook.

Comment: Sorry for confusion, I meant copy worksheet from another workbook to current workbook. Thanks!

Comment: So edit your question to state exactly what you mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you declare and use objects properly, you will not face this problem as you will be working with only those objects. Here is an example

```
Option Explicit

Dim wbThis As Workbook, wbThat As Workbook

Set wbThis = ThisWorkbook
Set wbThat = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\test.xlsm", ReadOnly:=True)

'
' Do some copying. For example see how I am using the objects below
' wbThat.Sheets("Sheet1").Copy After:=wbThis.Sheets(wbThis.Sheets.Count)
'

'~~> Close specific workbook when you are done
wbThat.Close (False)
```